Redirection problems with router-link in Vue.js: button does not return to another page
I recently started working on a Vue.js project. The purpose of my participation in the project was that the site has a Landing Page (App.vue), with several components that integrate App.vue, and I needed to create a second page (Site.vue) and redirect a button present in the "Telemedina.vue" component for this second page (Site.vue).
I installed router-link in the project using "npm install vue-router --force" smoothly.
The big problem is that I've already tried different ways to use the router-link, I've tried different scripts, I've had to resort to ChatGPT which also didn't help me practically at all, all because the button simply doesn't work. It changes the website URL, but simply does not redirect to any file.

Follow my router.js configuration code:

// router.js

import { createRouter, createWebHashHistory } from 'vue-router';
import App from './App.vue';
import Site from './Site.vue';

const routes = [
  { path: '/', component: App },
  { path: '/site', component: Site } //
];

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHashHistory(),
  routes
});

export default router;


Until then, when I press CTRL + click on the files in the imports, it actually redirects to the correct files, leaving my suspicions outside of router.js.

This is the button code present on Telemedina.vue and its script:

<router-link to="/site" class="custom-font" style="margin-top: 4vh; cursor: pointer;">Know more</router-link>

<script setup>
  import { useRouter } from 'vue-router';
  const router = useRouter();
</script>


And this is the main.js script:

// main.js

// Plugins
import { registerPlugins } from '@/plugins'

// Components
import App from './App.vue'
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import router from './router.js';

import "aos/dist/aos.css";

const app = createApp(App)

registerPlugins(app)

app.use(router);

app.mount('#app')

And when I click the button on the website, it changes the URL of "http://localhost:3000/#/" to "http://localhost:3000/#/site/", but it doesn't show the Site.vue file, it just changes the URL.
I need to create a "learn more" button in a Vue.js component so that it redirects to a second page. I tried with router-link, but I can't make the redirect button.

router-links change the current component seen in <router-view>, which you've not shown or you are not using.  Please make sure to read the Vue Router guide which is very helpful in explaining the behavior and proper use of Vue Router and it's different components.
